# Newlines within an array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I build an array as this :

```
arr = [s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 + s5 + s6]
```

I want to write that array into an HTML file. If I do, all elements of the array will be printed in line.

Now, I would like them to be written with new lines in between, like this :

s1 + s2

s3 + s4

s5 + s6

Comment: could you show us what array you are building? Now you'd count `s1+s2+..+s6` into a single element, leaving `arr = [ n ]`

Comment: what is s1, s2, s3,etc... ? Is that string or object? are you trying to add all objects?

Comment: each of them is a string

Comment: @harvey : This way array of string not defined. correct it with `arr = ["s1", " s2", "s3", "s4", "s5", "s6"]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array#each_slice`:

```
arr = ["s1" , "s2" , "s3" , "s4" , "s5" , "s6"]
arr.each_slice(2) { |a| p a }
# ["s1", "s2"]
# ["s3", "s4"]
# ["s5", "s6"]
```

Or more accurately:

```
file = File.open("abc.html", "w")
arr.each_slice(2) { |a| file.puts a.first + " + " + a.last }
file.close

File.read("abc")
# s1 + s2
# s3 + s4
# s5 + s6
```

Answer (score 1):

```
> arr = ["s1" , "s2" , "s3" , "s4" , "s5" , "s6"]
> arr.each_slice(2){|a| p "#{a[0]} + #{a[1]}"}
#output:
"s1 + s2"
"s3 + s4"
"s5 + s6"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you mean `arr = [s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6]`

Try

```
your_file.puts arr[0] + " + " + arr[1]
your_file.puts
your_file.puts arr[2]  + " + " +  arr[3]
your_file.puts
your_file.puts arr[4]  + " + " +  arr[5]
```

The blank `puts`s will add newlines between each row

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = %w(s1 s2 s3 s4 s5 s6)
while arr.length != 0
    puts arr.shift(2).join("+")
end
```

output:

```
s1+s2
s3+s4
s5+s6
```